# How to avoid screen reader reading label change while focusing the element?

Tags: html, accessibility, voiceover, jaws-screen-reader, nvda

When the user focus the element using tab, screen reader should read the aria-label or aria-describedby content. If user triggers any action from the same element then the content for aria-describedby will change, but the screen reader should not read the changed content. This content should be read by the screen reader only when focus enters the element next time. Is there any method or way to achieve this?

Comment: Is it reading changed content?

Comment: Yes, it is reading the changed content except JAWS. But I want the screen reader to avoid the change.

Comment: Have you checked where the focus was when it's reading?

Comment: what's the usecase for this? I think it's the expected behaviour to read it out immediately when it changes. Maybe you can change the aria-label only after the focus has exited?

Comment: It will remain in the same element. @lost_in_magento

Comment: @G-Unit - If you have any example for your suggestion that would be helpful.

Comment: I'm wondering about the use case as well. A screen reader user would probably identify the element as a new one when coming back. Does the visible information change as well?

Answer (score 2):

You can use `onblur` to check if your element has lost focus. Then change the aria-label. When the user comes back they will then get the aria-label read out to them.

I'd do something like this:

```
<element id="myElement" onblur="changeAriaLabel" arai-label="old-label">
```

in JS:

```js
changeAriaLabel(event) {
  if (userHasTriggeredAnActionAndTheLabelShouldChange) {
    const myElement = document.querySelector('#myElement'); // you can also get the element from the event, that's probably conidered cleaner code 
    myElement.ariaLabel = 'newLabel' // don't know exactly how to change the aria-label, but I think you know that already
  } else {
    console.log('nothing to change');
  }
}
```

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Reference/Events/blur

Comment: This is not an ideal solution for our situation, but you gave us a pretty good idea to solve our problem. Thanks. @G-Unit